# How can I get the keyboard Caps Lock state in Ubuntu

Tags: java

How to get caps lock status in Ubuntu? I was using

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

This works in Windows but not in Ubuntu.

Comment: I've just tested this on `Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit` using `IcedTea 2.5.6` and it works. Can you give more details about the JVM and Ubuntu version that you're using ?

Comment: Because runnning java doesn't depend on your operating system your code shown should work --> `boolean` returned

Comment: try {
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                     if(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK))
                {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
                }
                
            } catch (Exception E) {}

Comment: this is my code is it correct or not

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, this code will turn `Caps Lock` off if it is on and it works for me.

Comment: Robot robot = new Robot();  is this work in Ubuntu

Comment: Yes it does, maybe you don't have enough permission to use that or you're trying to use it on a system with no graphics environmen.